# How do I set fields in Thrift struct properly in C++ sources?

Tags: c++, thrift

I notice there is a method named `__set_FIELD` in the generated C++ class `MyThriftStruct` of my thrift structure `MyThriftStruct`. Calling this method will set the attribute `MyThriftStruct.__is_set.FIELD` to true which tells the structure this field has been set.

I also notice that in the [official tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/cpp) they set the filed of thrift structure by directly copying the value:

```
MyThriftStruct.FIELD = val;
```

The first method seems ugly but the latter one didn't change the `__isset` flag. So which one should I use to set the field of thrift struct in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends: for `required` fields or `default` (neither required nor optional) fields `MyThriftStruct.FIELD = val;` is enough.

`set_FIELD` is required only for optional fields (or manual modification of `__isset` struct fields is required to ensure optional field serialization)